# the ring $\frac{A[X]}{(X-a_{1},...,X-a_{n})}$ is isomorphic to A

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Can you please help me to show that : $$\frac{A[X]}{(X-a_{1},...,X-a_{n})}\simeq A$$ in which A is a ring and $a_{1},...,a_{n}\in A$.

thanks for your help.

Comment: That is in general false.

Answer (score 6):

This is not true, e.g.:

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(X-1,X-2)}\simeq 0\not\simeq \mathbb{Z}$$
simply because $X\equiv 1$ in the quotient (therefore any polynomial is equivalent to the sum of its coefficients), and $1\equiv 2$ therefore all elements of the quotient are equivalent to each other.

---

**Edit:** to be more precise, since $X-1\equiv 0$ in the quotient, and since $X^n-1$ is a multiple of $X-1$ for all $n$

> $$X^n-1=(X-1)(X^{n-1}+\ldots +1)$$

it follows that $X^n-1$ is also $0$, in other words $X^n\equiv 1$ for all $n$. Therefore any polynomial $a_nX^n+\ldots a_1X+a_0$ is equivalent to the integer $a_n+\ldots +a_0$.

Now since $X\equiv 2$ and $X\equiv 1$, it follows that $1\equiv 2$ (so that $0\equiv 1$ by subtracting $0$ on each side) and therefore all integers are in turn equivalent to $0$.

---

What you probably mean is that

$$\frac{A[X_1,\ldots, X_n]}{(X_1-a_{1},...,X_n-a_{n})}\simeq A$$

am I right?

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help, but i didn't follow why exactly $$\frac{Z[X]}{(X-1,X-2)}\simeq 0$$

Comment: @Amine $1 = (X-1) - (X-2) \in (X-1,X-2)$, so $(X-1, X-2) = \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: That's another approach, faster for sure, but I personally prefer to think in terms of what is equivalent to what.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Certainly, your approach is great (+1); I didn't notice you had edited to address the OP's comment.

Comment: thanks for your help sir.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thanks; it is also true that Amine might prefer a killing argument like the one you gave, and in any case always good to have several approaches at hand.

Comment: @Amine you're very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the quotient ring in two steps: let $I=(X-a_1)$, $J=(X-a_1,X-a_2,\dots,X-a_n)$; then
$$
A[X]/J\cong (A[X]/I)\big/(J/I)
$$
Now $A[X]/I\cong A$, via the homomorphism $\varphi\colon A[X]\to A$ defined by $\varphi(a)=a$, for $a\in A$, and $\varphi(X)=a_1$, which has kernel $I$.

If we consider $K=\varphi(J)$, we get that
$$
A[X]/J\cong A/K
$$
which is generally not isomorphic to $A$. You can check that
$$
K=(a_1-a_2,\dots,a_1-a_n)
$$

Comment: Thanks so much .